# Can't remove Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I installed Eclipse and now can't remove it.

I've already tried

```
sudo apt-get purge eclipse
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
```

which does not work.

I want to uninstall Eclipse since I tried everything to fix the bug which freezes Eclipse every time I try to create a new project or a new class or anything.

Comment: That's most likely because you installed it outside of the package manager - for example, by extracting a tarball that you downloaded from the Eclipse site. Identifying where the binary and associated files are would be a good start e.g. `which eclipse` and/or `whereis eclipse`

Comment: Please describe how you installed Eclipse or link the guide you followed. How to uninstall it depends on how it got installed. We can't give any valuable advice without that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you download from [eclipse website](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) and extract **.tar** file to **Specified directory** so if you want to remove eclipse :

1. Go to this directory and remove eclipse folder on my laptop `/opt/eclipse`.
2. Run this command `whereis eclipse` and remove output directories.
3. If you create specific Launcher icon go to `/usr/share/applications` or `directory you create in` and remove it (it will need permission so open your file manager as a root).